# Checkboxes when submitted not returning as expected

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I'm trying to understand why my checkboxes are not being submitted as a user_id array, can anyone help me figure out why? I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

```
// View
{{ Form::model($process, array('route' => array('judi.processes.update', $process->id), 'method' => 'put') ) }}

@foreach ($assessors->users as $assessor)
    {{ Form::checkbox( 'user_id[]', $assessor->id, checkboxState( $assessor->id, $process->users()->lists('user_id') ) ) }}
@endforeach

{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}

{{ Form::close() }}

// Controller
$users = Input::get('user_id');

// Output
Users 
[
  0 =>'1' 
  1 =>'106' 
  2 =>'107'
]

// Looking for
Users

'user_id' = [
  0 => '1',
  1 => '106',
  2 => '107'
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's some weird functionality when using `Input::get()`, where if you only get one thing, it returns it as an array; in your case:

```
array(3) { [0] =>'1', [1] =>'106', [2] =>'107'] }
```

Try changing `Input::get('user_id')` to:

```
$users = Input::only('user_id');
```

And check the results. It should now be formatted as:

```
array(1) { ['user_id'] => array(3) { [0] => '1', [1] => '106', [2] => '107'] } }
```

Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are using `Input::get('user_id')`, it **is** the desired behavior.

To get what you are looking for, I guess you should use `Input::all()`